# How to replace multiple values with other conditional strings or int values in a Pandas Dataframe/Series

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm dealing with a huge excel sheet, about 176k rows of raw data and I need to replace multiple values from one column with conditionals from another column, something like "if column A has written 'word' in any row, then replace(str1, str2) in column B of the same row"

I've done another replacements with replace function using lists:

```
list1 = ["..","...","..."]

list2 = ["..","...","..."]

df['column'] = df['column'].replace(
    list1, list2)
```

This has worked perfectly... but now I need to do multiple replacements:

for example, current df:

```
      a       b
0   value1  value5
1   value2  value5
2   value3  value5
```

Excpected output:

```
      a       b
0   value1  x-value
1   value2  y-value
2   value3  z-value
```

In the example I would need to replace the column "b" with another value with the condition of the objects (str or int) of column a0, a1, a2, so the condition would be "== (value1, value2, value3)". The resulting value in the "b" could be anything.

I've also tried this for loop but it replaces other values I don't want:

```
for i in df['column1']:
     
     if i in df['column1'] == 'value1':
         
        df['column2'] = df['column2'].replace("value2", "value3")
```

I have tried with subsetting also but didn't work:

```
new_df = df['column1'] == "value1"

new = df[new_df]

df['column2'] = new['column2'].replace('value2', 'value3')
```

Comment: This is a pretty well-written question, but will you please always do two simple things when dealing with Pandas question: 1. include text, not images, of your (sample) dataframe, and 2. include a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: Thank you!, edited

Comment: Will please also provide samples of your lists?\

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood about your problem, you want to changed the values of a redundant column based on three conditions: copy the values of another column but changed a few things to fit the attributes of this revised column. In that case try this...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Five'], 'Col2': ['differ', '', '', '', '']})

print(df)


def replacefunc(data, char1, char2):
    for a, b in zip(data['Col1'], data['Col2']):
        if a != b:
            data['Col2'] = data['Col1'].replace(char1, char2)
    return data


df = replacefunc(df, 4, 'changed')

print(df)
```

Output:

previous_df

```
Col1    Col2
0     1  differ
1     2        
2     3        
3     4        
4  Five
```

new_df

```
Col1     Col2
0     1        1
1     2        2
2     3        3
3     4  changed
4  Five     Five
```